# How do I retrieve a listing of a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I carry a list with information that comes from my database. This is displayed in a form where the user can edit a field. My intention is when they click the save button this list being displayed for him would pass as a parameter to a method. I'm lost, what is wrong?

View

```
@model Teste.Models.Produto

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "ListaProdutoCab", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selecione</th>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Valor</th>

            </tr>
        </thead> @foreach (var item in Model.listaBebida)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.isEditado)</td>
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.produto, new { disabled = "disabled" }) </td>
                <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.valor) </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="botoes">
            <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Teste.DAO;
using Teste.Models;

namespace Teste.Controllers
{
    public class ListaProdutoCab: Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /ListaProdutoCab/
        ListaProdutoService service = new ListaProdutoService();
        Produto produto = new Produto();
        Session usuario = new Session("Genisson", 058);

        List<ObjectMasterProduto> listaProduto= new List<ObjectMasterProduto>();

        public ActionResult ListaProdutoCab()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult List()

        {
            service.carregarListaBebida(produto.listaBebida);
            return PartialView(produto);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Salvar(Produto produto)
        {
            service.Salvar(produto.listaBebida, usuario);
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }

    }
}
```

my entity

Produto

```
public class Produto
{
    //Chamadas externas
    public Bebida bebida{ get; set; }

    public List<Bebida> listaBebida{ get; set; }

    public Produto()
    {

    }
}
```

my other entity, Class bebida

```
public class Bebida
{
    //Chamadas externas
    public String nome{ get; set; }

    public Double Valor{ get; set; }

    public Bebida()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: the product value back to null , as if the object was not loaded , however it has been loaded into the method : carregarListaProduto

Comment: None of your actions have any parameters, so how are you retrieving values entered by the user? Normally you need to create a Model class (like you have), but you need to pass them back.

Comment: Its a Strongly-typed of Produto, But I tried using the 'save' method this way :
public ActionResult Save ( Product item)
        {
            service.Salvar ( item.listaBebida , User ) ;
            RedirectToAction return ( "List" ) ;
        }

passing as parameter my product object and taking a property of the same, but the object still returns null. It will be the reason for this is why I'm using an object within it is a list of other? and we display a list of that other object?

Comment: The code you have in the comment below is a good start. However, you have to make sure you "record" the list in the view. This is a bit strange to explain. You know how to pass a value (like a string or int) to your view and display it. In order to get it back your view needs to use it, and your POST method must ask for it back (from your model). Lists are tricky because you have to "use" all the values in the list.

Comment: that is the great doubt , as I ask this list back to my controller? even more the case of a list .... there is a way to get this object completely in the controller? and I treat it later in my service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of a `foreach` loop is creating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to you model and therefore cannot be bound to your model when you submit. Change it to a `for` loop

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.listaBebida.Count, i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listaBebida[i].isEditado)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaBebida[i].produto)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listaBebida[i].valor) </td>
  </tr>
}
```

This will generate the correct name attributes, for example

```
<input type="text" name="listaBebida[0].valor" ... />
<input type="text" name="listaBebida[1].valor" ... />
<input type="text" name="listaBebida[2].valor" ... />
```

Side note: You have included the `disabled` attribute for `produto` which means that property will be null in the model when you submit (disabled form controls do not post back a value). If you want binding, then make it `readonly`

Answer (score -1):

in these cases which values of some list should be posted, get values from form manually without model binding.

In your question i'm considering you have a unique identifier in your `Bebida` class like `Bebida.Id`, so the sample code may be:
 such this:

```
@model Teste.Models.Produto

@{
    Layout = null;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salvar", "ListaProdutoCab", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selecione</th>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Valor</th>

            </tr>
        </thead> @foreach (var item in Model.listaBebida)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> <input type='checkbox' name='chk_@item.Id' /> </td>
                <td> <input type='text' name='produto_@item.Id' /> </td>
                <td> <input type='text' name='valor_@item.Id' /> </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div id="modal">
        <div id="botoes">
            <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

and in your action :

```
           [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Salvar()
            {
              var checkboxkeys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k=>k.Contains("chk_"));
              var CheckedCheckboxesId =checkboxkeys.Select(k=> Convert.ToInt32( k.Substring(4,k.Length-4)));

              var produtokeys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k=>k.Contains("produto_"));
              var produtos= new Dictionary<int,string>();
              foreach(var item in produtokeys )
              {
                  produtos.Add(Convert.ToInt32( item.Substring(8,k.Length-8)),Request.Form[item]);
              }


              var valorkeys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(k=>k.Contains("valor_"));
              var valors= new Dictionary<int,string>();
              foreach(var item in valorkeys )
              {
                  valors.Add(Convert.ToInt32( item.Substring(6,k.Length-6)),Request.Form[item]);
              }

              // in here you have CheckedCheckboxesId, produtos and valors and you may want store them.

              return RedirectToAction("List");
            }
```